# How is it that chomp is able to change the value of a variable not passed by reference?

Tags: perl

`chomp` seems to be able to change the value of a variable not passed by reference; that is, the syntax is `chomp $var` instead of `chomp \$var`.

How is this possible?  How can I imitate this behavior in a function?

`chomp`:

```perl
my $var="foo\n";
chomp $var;
print $var
```

`mychomp`:

```perl
my $var="foo\n";
mychomp(\$var);
print $var;

sub mychomp {
  my $ref=shift;
  $$ref=~s/\s+$//;
}
```

Comment: You're confusing "passing a reference" and "passing by reference". In Perl, arguments are always passed by reference, so changing the elements of `@_` changes the corresponding variables in the caller..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All Perl parameters are "passed by reference"; more accurately, the contents of `@_` are *aliases* for the actual parameters

Observe

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $s = 'abc';

upper_case($s);

say $s;


sub upper_case {
  $_[0] =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
}
```

#### output

```
ABC
```

Note that calling this function with a data literal, such as

```
upper_case('def')
```

will generate the fatal error

```
Modification of a read-only value attempted
```

Comment: Or, since the user asked about `chomp`, `sub mychomp { $_[0] =~ s/\s+\z//; }`. Or more accurately, `sub mychomp { my $c = 0; for (@_) { $c += length($/) if s{\Q$/\E\z}{}; } $c }`

Comment: I recommend instead `sub convert_to_uppercase { for (@_) { $_ = uc } }` since that works no matter how many arguments or whether they are old ASCII or modern Unicode text. Some people would write that `$_ = uc for @_`  I suppose.